# Динамическое добавление html в dom с помощью JS

Tags: javascript

Есть такой  [код](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmJMMQ?editors=1111) . В данном случае я вручную создаю каждую ячейку,заполняю ее и вставляю в ряд.но в данном случае табличка маленькая. И я подумал,что когда таблица будет скажем на 10 колонок для каждой создавать ячейку в ручную это совсем не дело... Собственно вопрос,как можно добавить ряд в табличку "малой кровью"?
Также интересует такой вопрос. В данном случае я добавлял просто текст с помощью метода `textContent`,но если в таблицу надо будет добавить кнопку и структура ячейки будет:

```
<td>
<button></button>(или <a></a>)
</td>
```

Как можно в таком случае добавить такой HTML?

Comment: про вставку всё есть ту https://learn.javascript.ru/multi-insert. большего к ответу не добавить.

Answer (score -1):

Можешь установить в свою среду разработки emmet и простое написание:

```
table>tr*10>td*5
```

и нажатием клавиши tab создаст таблицу на 10 рядов и 5 ячеек в каждом ряду.

```
  <table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

С помощью JS можешь добавлять так:

```
$('table tr:last-child').after('<tr><a href=""></a></tr>')
```

Comment: Эмм. Вариант то норм, но это не совсем ответ.

Comment: Автор вроде как спрашивает про динамическое добавление, а не про облегчение статического формирования HTML при разработке.

Comment: @olezha $('table tr:last-child').after('<tr><a href=""></a></tr>') это не JS, это jquery.